# Xcode spritekit scene editor with node

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I want to add a physics body to a node in the scene edit by spritekit editor, any one can show me how?
ps: I can add physics body to a sprite, it works fine, but to node, code is the only works way by now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can via the Scene Editor but I am not sure why you can't, given the `SKPhysicsBody` is a property of `SKNode` and not `SKSpriteNode`.

You could try:

1. Creating a sprite with a transparent texture.
2. Doing it in code.

The scene editor is very lacking and in my game I am seriously considering writing a custom editor to overcome the limitations.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the transparent to test.